# About time complexity of the algorithm

Tags: c++, string

I am trying to solve the following question from [LeetCode.com](https://leetcode.com/problems/reverse-words-in-a-string/description/):

> Given an input string, reverse the string word by word.  Thus, "the sky is blue" should become "blue is sky the".

I came up with the following code snippet:

```
class Solution {
public:
    void reverseWords(string &s) {
        if(s.empty()) return;

        istringstream iss(s);
        string data, ans;
        while(iss>>data) {
            ans.insert(0, data+" ");
        }

        s=ans.substr(0,ans.size()-1);
    }
};
```

and I was wondering about the time complexity of the same.  I think that it is `O(n^2)` where `n` is the number of words in the input string.  Could someone please confirm?

Thanks. (^_^)

Comment: Bother to explain the downvote?  MVCE, silly question, just bored, great fun -  what?

Comment: Where does n*n come from?

Comment: `ans.substr(0,ans.size()-1);` how does this differ from `ans;`?

Comment: `istringstream` uses an `O(n)` and appending at the beginning (and resulting in consequent moves) uses another `O(n)`.

Comment: Isn’t that 2*n?

Comment: @manni66, :)  It differs because the last space is truncated.

Comment: @manni66,  I am not sure, hence I am asking this question (and getting downvoted, perhaps!).

Comment: Have you tried to measure the time for sentences of length 1, 2, 3, ... ? This way you can easily validate any answer

Comment: @Omni, what do you mean?  How can I measure the time to determine the time complexity?

Comment: @manni66 - do your homework on complexity.   O(n) and O(2*n) are equivalent.

Comment: You only can take number of words as n if they all are (almost) the same size.

Comment: @Peter, so is the complexity `O(n^2)`?  I am unsure because I am using `istringstream`.

Comment: Nope.   Look up what the complexity is for streaming a string.   And what the complexity is for inserting a string.   In each case, complexity is related to number of characters being streamed or inserted, not number of words.

Comment: @Peter, I agree, but both `stringstream` and `insert()` are working on words.  I am doubtful about insertion just because I am inserting at the beginning (resulting in movement of subsequent words).

Comment: Thank you for the motivating downvotes!  Please keep them coming in! XD

Comment: @peter where did you find big O in my comments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this algorithm's complexity is a bit more (haha) complex than other answers assume, intuitively down to the fact that we're **prepending** (not appending) and looping, and also because there's a bit of oversimplifying going on.

---

To be formal (and correct), the other analyses here aren't using enough variables - let's call `w` the number of words in the sentence and `l` the maximum length of a word in this sentence.

Then `iss >> data` is `O(w)` ("at most as expensive as the longest word"). Over `l` iterations of the loop, this is `O(lw)`.

---

`ans.insert(0, data + " ")` is more complicated - `insert` is `O(x + y)` for `x` the length of the existing content and `y` the length of the new content. As the length of the existing content keeps growing (adding at most `w` each time), the complexity of this function isn't entirely obvious.

The cost of performing `l` prepends is at most `w + 2w + 3w + ... + lw` - each iteration we have to pay for all the words we've previously added as well as the word we're just adding now. This has a [closed form expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF):
`w(1+2+...+l) = w * l(l+1)/2`, and this is `O(w*l^2)`.

---

Putting it together, the cost of the loop is `O(wl + w*l^2)`, which is just `O(w*l^2)`. It's informally "quadratic", but it depends on more than just one variable `n`, so it's best to classify it as a function of all the relevant ones.

---

Ps. One of the easy mistakes to make with big O notation is to always just talk about `n` - but what is `n`? In this example, we depend on more than just one variable, so using `n` can be misleading. `insert` is `O(n)` where `n` is the new length - but if you're already talking about `n` with regards to some other parameter (like the number of words), mistakes will happen.

PPs. Please point out mistakes/corrections in my analysis!

PPPs. [`insert` isn't guaranteed to be `O(x + y)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/append) as I claimed above - but it's safe to assume this complexity.

Comment: Wow!  One answer finally that makes sense.  Thank you.  You understand my problem clearly and I understand your solution.

Comment: Glad to hear it helped - lots of big O questions get asked on SO, and more often than not the answers aren't reaaaaally all that comprehensive. You might want to consider asking these more-CS-theory-based questions on [cs.se](https://cs.stackexchange.com/), they're more mathematical over there.

Comment: As for your "PPs" - I don't think anyone will do that.  You should understand something's amiss if you get downvoted.  That's the only way we get helped most of the times (unless someone noble like you appears!).

Answer (score -3):

The complexity is `O(N)`, as correctly explained by J.Doe

> `istringstream` uses an `O(n)` and appending at the beginning (and resulting in consequent moves) uses another `O(n)`

See here the explanation, why the constant 2 is not relevant:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Example

> If f(x) is a product of several factors, any constants (terms in the product that do not depend on x) can be omitted.

Comment: But this extraction is being done in the while loop; and in each iteration, I am also appending words to the beginning of the string `ans`.  So is the complexity `O(n^2)` or `O(n)`?

Comment: You are right, because of this it's propably `O(N²)`. Please vote down my answer :-)

Comment: That's totally alright.  I won't.  Then there would be no difference between me and others here.  Even I am not sure, that's why I am asking and these guys are downvoting me!

Comment: For clarification: 
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/append
claims that there is no complexity guarantee for `string::append` but it behaves often like `vector::insert` at the end. 
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert
Version (4) of `vector::insert` depends linear on distance between the insertion position and the end of the container. For inserting at the beginning, it thus depends linearly on N. Therefore I would assume that the line `ans.insert(0, data+" ");` in your code has complexity `O(N)`.

Comment: **Disclaimer:** I am not the one who has downvoted the answer.  In fact, if I could, I would have upvoted it!

Comment: Yes, so that `insert()` is `O(n)` and `iss>>data` (in the same iteration) is `O(n)`, which makes it `O(n^2)`, as per my knowledge.

Comment: You are taking efforts to help me, so I have accepted your answer.  Thanks!

Comment: Guys, vector complexity is measured against n as a number of elements in vector, that it number of characters in the string.
Original question is about complexity for n as number of words, which is different.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

Comment: @AlexeyVoytenko, why comment when you could answer?

Comment: This answer is only correct if you assume that the strings being fed into the algorithm are always the same length - otherwise there's a missing parameter in the analysis. Given that there's no such constraint in the question, I'd argue that this answer is incorrect.

Comment: Your claim is incorrect. Go back and read the original question. Let me cite: "I think that it is O(n^2) where n is the number of words in the input string.".